# Is it possile to set some item unclickable in ListView or GridView on Android?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

Is it possile to set some item unclickable in ListView or GridView on Android?
For example, if user click item 0, I want to set item 1 cannot be click.
But if handle in onItemClick method, it still can click and change color.
I want it cannot be click means item click but do nothing.
My code as below:

```
GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gv);
gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        if(position == 0) {
            //set item 1 unclickable
        }
    }
});
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        if(position == 0) {
            //set item 1 unclickable
        }
    }
});
```

How can I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one problem with what you want to achieve. If - for example - the item that you want to disable is not currently visible in `ListView` because user have smaller screen and it doesn't fit the size of `ListView`, this item doesn't yet have any `View` assigned to it. This means that you can't really make this item not clickable, because it doesn't exist.

Solution which Avadhani Y posted is wrong, because it makes the item that you just clicked not clickable and you want to alter another item.

What you want then is to create your own `Adapter` for `ListView` (if you don't yet use your custom `Adapter`) and override `getView()` method, like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private List<String> items;
    public boolean itemAtPos0Clicked = false;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(position == 1 && itemAtPos0Clicked) {
            convertView.setClickable(false);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And your `OnItemClickListener` for `ListView` should look like this:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        if((position == 0) && (lv.getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0)) {
            ((MyAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).itemAtPos0Clicked = true;
            ((MyAdapter)lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

I didn't test it or anything, so you will probably have to fix few errors.

Comment: It does not work. `(MyAdapter)(lv.getAdapter()).itemAtPos0Clicked = true;` is completely wrong.

Comment: Because you probably didn't even create `MyAdapter` class which I also posted in my answer.

Comment: Oh! I see. I have taken the code u posted and compiled, run. I am saying again that it does not work. Why cant you compile and check once?

Comment: Please dont say that "Now it should be ok.", Please try to say "Now it is ok.". I think u understand what i am trying to say

Comment: No, because I'm not totally sure it will work as it should, because I don't have time for making a test application for this. I gave an idea of how to solve the problem OP has and additionaly posted a code which I don't guarantee it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that as below:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    if(position == 0) {
        arg1.findViewById(R.id.lv).setClickable(false);
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It doesn't make second item to be not clickable, but this one that was clicked. It's not what he wants.

Comment: @PiotrChojnacki I cant get u.

Comment: What he wants is: user clicks item at position 0 and then item at position 1 is being disabled. And you give him: user clicks item at position 0 and item at position 0 is disabled.

Comment: I think it cannot be acheived.

Comment: Ok. Can u please post it as an answer, will be helpful for others who are searching for same type of solution???